How to solve "Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor." error in Xcode?
I signed my project to development account in Xcode 15.3. Whatever I try, Xcode shows:

/Users/faridahmadov/flutter-projects/barsiba/ios/Runner.xcodeproj Signing for "RunnerTests" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.

Here you can see I have selected all option and team in capability row

I logout from Apple Dev account in Xcode. However it did not help me.
